# Exector Error while using multithreading

Tags: ros-humble, nav2, multi-robot, multithreading

I am currently working on migrating a ROS1 project to ROS2, I am using a multithreaded executor to have concurrent callbacks, I have an error I am unfamiliar with. Does anyone have had this error? if yes can you guide me to correct it?

Here is the error I have :

```
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/home/user/multirobot_interface/ROS2_Warehouse_Simulation/colcon_ws/install/turtlebot3_multi_robot/lib/turtlebot3_multi_robot/robot_task_allocator.py", line 189, in <module>
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     mt_executor.spin()
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 294, in spin
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self.spin_once()
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 794, in spin_once
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 791, in _spin_once_impl
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     future.result()
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 94, in result
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     raise self.exception()
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 239, in __call__
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self._handler.send(None)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 437, in handler
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     await call_coroutine(entity, arg)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 362, in _execute_subscription
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     await await_or_execute(sub.callback, msg)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 107, in await_or_execute
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     return callback(*args)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/home/user/multirobot_interface/ROS2_Warehouse_Simulation/colcon_ws/install/turtlebot3_multi_robot/lib/turtlebot3_multi_robot/robot_task_allocator.py", line 82, in task_callback
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self.set_task(msg.assignee_id, msg.stations, msg.id)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/home/user/multirobot_interface/ROS2_Warehouse_Simulation/colcon_ws/install/turtlebot3_multi_robot/lib/turtlebot3_multi_robot/robot_task_allocator.py", line 124, in set_task
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     result = command.go_to_multiple_goals(waypoints)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/home/user/multirobot_interface/ROS2_Warehouse_Simulation/colcon_ws/install/turtlebot3_multi_robot/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/turtlebot3_multi_robot/command.py", line 241, in go_to_multiple_goals
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     while not self.navigator.isTaskComplete():
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nav2_simple_commander/robot_navigator.py", line 284, in isTaskComplete
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, self.result_future, timeout_sec=0.10)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 248, in spin_until_future_complete
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     executor.spin_until_future_complete(future, timeout_sec)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 310, in spin_until_future_complete
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self.spin_once_until_future_complete(future, timeout_left)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 746, in spin_once_until_future_complete
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 728, in _spin_once_impl
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     handler, entity, node = self.wait_for_ready_callbacks(timeout_sec=timeout_sec)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 711, in wait_for_ready_callbacks
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     return next(self._cb_iter)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 630, in _wait_for_ready_callbacks
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     if wt in waitables and wt.is_ready(wait_set):
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/action/client.py", line 231, in is_ready
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     ready_entities = self._client_handle.is_ready(wait_set)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5] rclpy._rclpy_pybind11.RCLError: Failed to get number of ready entities for action client: wait set index for cancel client is out of bounds, at ./src/rcl_action/action_client.c:631
```

And sometimes this error:

```
[robot_task_allocator.py-5] Traceback (most recent call last):
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/home/asazjaathmohamed/multirobot_interface/ROS2_Warehouse_Simulation/colcon_ws/install/turtlebot3_multi_robot/lib/turtlebot3_multi_robot/robot_task_allocator.py", line 190, in <module>
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     mt_executor.spin()
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 294, in spin
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self.spin_once()
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 794, in spin_once
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 791, in _spin_once_impl
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     future.result()
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 94, in result
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     raise self.exception()
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 239, in __call__
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self._handler.send(None)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 437, in handler
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     await call_coroutine(entity, arg)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 362, in _execute_subscription
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     await await_or_execute(sub.callback, msg)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 107, in await_or_execute
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     return callback(*args)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/home/asazjaathmohamed/multirobot_interface/ROS2_Warehouse_Simulation/colcon_ws/install/turtlebot3_multi_robot/lib/turtlebot3_multi_robot/robot_task_allocator.py", line 82, in task_callback
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self.set_task(msg.assignee_id, msg.stations, msg.id)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/home/asazjaathmohamed/multirobot_interface/ROS2_Warehouse_Simulation/colcon_ws/install/turtlebot3_multi_robot/lib/turtlebot3_multi_robot/robot_task_allocator.py", line 124, in set_task
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     result = command.go_to_multiple_goals(waypoints)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/home/asazjaathmohamed/multirobot_interface/ROS2_Warehouse_Simulation/colcon_ws/install/turtlebot3_multi_robot/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/turtlebot3_multi_robot/command.py", line 241, in go_to_multiple_goals
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     while not self.navigator.isTaskComplete():
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nav2_simple_commander/robot_navigator.py", line 284, in isTaskComplete
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, self.result_future, timeout_sec=0.10)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 248, in spin_until_future_complete
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     executor.spin_until_future_complete(future, timeout_sec)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 310, in spin_until_future_complete
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self.spin_once_until_future_complete(future, timeout_left)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 746, in spin_once_until_future_complete
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 728, in _spin_once_impl
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     handler, entity, node = self.wait_for_ready_callbacks(timeout_sec=timeout_sec)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 711, in wait_for_ready_callbacks
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     return next(self._cb_iter)
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 630, in _wait_for_ready_callbacks
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     if wt in waitables and wt.is_ready(wait_set):
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]   File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos_event.py", line 90, in is_ready
[robot_task_allocator.py-5]     if wait_set.is_ready('event', self._event_index):
[robot_task_allocator.py-5] IndexError: wait set index too big
``

Thank you.
```